# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, connection-refused

I got this error: **curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused** when i typed **curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'**. I setup elasticsearch 1.7 and after that i edited file elasticsearch.yum:

- cluster.name: elasticsearch
- node.name: "Elasticsearch"
- network.bind_host: localhost
- network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
- network.host: 0.0.0.0

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try looking at your logs for additional information on errors and try restarting your elastic search server.

Comment: Please provide the logs of your installation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/_installation.html

Comment: Thank you all for your supports. I fixed this problem I forgot to assign permissions on /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch

Comment: ^ Thanks. I did `sudo chmod u+w /var/lib/elasticsearch` and then my `sudo curl -X GET "localhost:9200"` oddly started working.